# Unable to find Artifactory Project in Visual Studio Extensions and Updates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, artifactory

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to add JFrog Artifactory Project to push artifacts to Artifactory.

To add Artifactory project I need to install it from tools--> Extensions and Updates--> search for Artifactory. But the search results is zero.

So how can i install JFrog Artifactory in Visual Studio 2017. It is working fine with Visual studio 2015.

Comment: Doing a search with a (Visual Studio) version filter shows no extensions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Artifactory&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs15&sortBy=Relevance Seems they've not updated their extensions. Create a project in VS2015 and then use in VS2017?

Comment: Richard is true, the extensin has not been updated yet for VS2017 but you can create the project with VS2015 and then open it with VS2015.